# ERROR: Could not create unique index PSQL

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I am currently working on my psql my first psql database as created below:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS test_table_a;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS test_table_b;

CREATE TABLE test_table_a (
    test_name_a varchar (150) NOT NULL,
    test_num_a integer NOT NULL
);
ALTER TABLE test_table_a OWNER TO me;

CREATE TABLE test_table_b (
    test_name_b varchar (150) NOT NULL,
    test_num_b integer NOT NULL
);
ALTER TABLE test_table_b OWNER TO me;

CREATE TABLE test_table_c (
    test_name_a varchar (150) NOT NULL,
    test_num_a integer  NOT NULL,
    test_num_b integer NOT NULL,
    test_name_b varchar(150) NOT NULL,

);
ALTER TABLE test_table_c OWNER TO me;
```

Then I load it with data...:

```
echo COPY test_table_a FROM location_x
psql -c "COPY (
    SELECT DISTINCT
        test_num_a,
        test_name_a,
    FROM location_x
  ) TO STDOUT;" location_x | \
  psql -c "COPY test_table_a FROM STDIN;" me

echo COPY test_table_b FROM location_x
psql -c "COPY (
    SELECT DISTINCT
        test_num_b,
        test_name_b,
    FROM location_x
  ) TO STDOUT;" location_x | \
  psql -c "COPY test_table_b FROM STDIN;" me


echo COPY test_table_c FROM location_x
psql -c "COPY (
    SELECT DISTINCT
        test_num_a,
        test_name_a,
        test_num_b,
        test_name_b
    FROM location_x
  ) TO STDOUT;" location_x | \
  psql -c "COPY test_table_c FROM STDIN;" me
```

And then I try to add keys, which is when I generate the following errors:

`ERROR: could not create unique index "pk_test_num_a"
DETAIL: KEY (test_num_a) = (128)  is duplicated.
ERROR: could not create unique index "pk_test_num_b"
DETAIL: KEY (test_num_b) = (110)  is duplicated.`

When I run:

```
ALTER TABLE divDemographic
    ADD CONSTRAINT pk_test_num_b PRIMARY KEY (test_num_b);

ALTER TABLE schDemographic
    ADD CONSTRAINT pk_test_num_a PRIMARY KEY (test_num_a);

ALTER TABLE test_table_c
    ADD CONSTRAINT fk_test_num_a FOREIGN KEY (test_num_a) REFERENCES test_table_a(test_num_a),
    ADD CONSTRAINT fk_test_num_b FOREIGN KEY (test_num_b) REFERENCES test_table_b(test_num_b);
```

I thought that using the "duplicate" specifier in the select statements would prevent this, any thoughts on how to fix this error? thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`SELECT DISTINCT` detects duplicate rows by comparing all selected columns: clearly you have rows with *test_num_a*=128 and a different *test_name_a*, which are distinct.

Either the content of your source table *location_x* is defective or you cannot actually use *test_num_a* as a primary key.

Comment: That makes sense...I think test_num_a may have multiple test_num_b for each test_num_a value...ill try that out, and get back to you thanks